# Best architecture to work with JMenuBar in Java (similar to MVC)

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jmenubar

I searched many places trying to find information or examples of how to incorporate a `JMenuBar` in ***mvc architecture***. And I fail to understand how to do this.

The idea is that each *`menu item`* has its own associated *`panel`*. These *`panels`* are inserted in the *`main frame`* depending on the selection menu.

In this context, the best way to approach this is to have a great driver for all *`views`* or a *`sub-controller`* for each *`view`*?

And if this was not the most appropriate. ***MVC*** is the best ***architecture*** to do this or is there another more appropriate architecture?

Comment: The idea is that each menu item has its own associated panel. == CardLayout

Comment: Swing already takes an MVC approach. Most(maybe all, haven't looked) JComponents are simply controllers with associated Model objects. It's not strictly MVC as there's a lot of crossover between Controller and View. That said, this is a pretty vague question.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But I'm wondering ***architectures***

Comment: Use [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html); more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).